# Python3 Win32com Copy body of an email and paste to a new excel file

Tags: email, copy-paste, win32com

I'm trying to copy paste an html table received by outlook email to a new excel spreadsheet but I get a "pywintypes.com_error."  Seeking a more pythonic way to do a the equivalent of a "Control+A" on an email body and paste to a new spreadsheet.

The relevant pieces of code are:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

try:
    for message in messages:
        try:
            if message.subject == 'myemailed Report':
                print('Sender:' , message.sender)
                print(message.subject)

                mailItem = message.HTMLBody # <----Attempting to copy the body of the selected email.

                # Start an instance of Excel
                Xlsx = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

                # Prevent Excel from asking questions.
                Xlsx.DisplayAlerts = True # will change to False
                Xlsx.Visible = True # will change to False

                # Create a new Excel Workbook
                workbook = Xlsx.Workbooks.Add()
                ws = workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
                ws.Range('a7').select

                ws.Paste(mailItem) # <--------------- Generates Error

                workbook.SaveAs(mydesktop+'UpdatedSheet.xlsx')

                # Quit Excel
                Xlsx.Quit()

        except:
            x=1

except:
    x=1
```

I get a message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    ws.Paste(mailItem)
  File ">", line 3, in Paste
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Paste method of Worksheet class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Is there a better way?  Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ws.Paste(mailItem) is the main part of the problem.  Code should be:

```
ws.Paste()
```

However - copying the email body as if hitting "Ctrl-A" is a little more involved and there are a lot of almost answers.  I managed to get the following work but I don't know why it works.

I used import pyperclip which requires pip install pyperclip, along with the following code:

```
import pyperclip

def copy(text):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(text, win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
def paste():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return data
```

Then later on...

```
        mailItem = message.HTMLBody
        pyperclip.copy(mailItem)

        # Start an instance of Excel
        Xlsx = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

        # Create a new Excel Workbook
        workbook = Xlsx.Workbooks.Add()

        ws = workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ws.Range('a1').select
        ws.Paste()
        ws.Range('a1').select

        workbook.SaveAs(myexcel.xlsx')
```

I tried doing this without using pyperclip but the combination of the two def's in the beginning and the ws.Paste() worked.